# html syntax in next.js destroyed When I save the index.js file

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, next.js, syntax-error

I'm facing a problem in VSCode, I'm currently working on a next.js project, the problem is when I try to save the index.js file the HTML syntax is crashing, I don't know how to solve it, please help and thank you in advance

before saving [screenshot_before_saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhXBa.png)

after saving [screenshot_after_saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5TP.png)

Comment: As Tomas said, check your "format on save" and formatter options in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

well, this is just a guess but vs code may be interpreting your file wrong. It thinks it is just plain js but it is actually js + jsx and so you need to change the file from .js to .jsx. but to be honest it should work either way. just a guess.

Comment: thank's it work< there was an XML format plugin when I uninstalled it, it worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I happened because I have two formatter,
you should disable the js-css-html formatter and user prettier formatter